# How should I wire this stereo jack for a mono plug?

Tags: soldering

I have two of these [stereo jacks](http://docs-asia.electrocomponents.com/webdocs/0569/0900766b805698ff.pdf) that I am planning on using to rewire some headphones that have had the original cable fail somewhere between the speaker and the end plug. Instead of bothering to fix the existing cable, I plan to replace the cable entirely but also give them the ability to have a removable cable. The replacement cable has 1x 3.5mm stereo plug on one end and 2x 2.5mm mono plugs on the other end.

What I'm not sure of is whether or not there is an optimal pole to resolder when using a mono plug in this (stereo) jack?

For anyone curious, the final product:

[image: Final product]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the tip and sleeve contacts (1 and 3).  The ring contact (2) will contact the sleeve on a mono plug.

Comment: For clarification, would it make a technical different if I soldered the ring and tip instead?

Comment: @MichaelFrank: ring and tip should work too, but it is normal practice to connect the shield or common lead to the sleeve.  If you use the ring and tip, you may get unwanted effects if you happen to plug in a stereo cable.